# Killing background process in bash script when exiting the script

Tags: bash, shell-script, kill, trap

I have a script that `tail` a file **while displaying a clock in the top right corner**. I took the clock part from the internet, and it works ok. The entire script is something like (I simplified):

```
while sleep 1; do tput sc; tput cup 0 $(($(tput cols)-29)); date; tput rc; done &
tail -f mylog.log
```

All works well, but the problem is that **when I stop the script** using `CTRL+C` the clock continues to run in my console (until I manually kill the left-over bash process). So, *is there a way to stop that process when I quit the script?*

I tried the code below, but it does not work:

```
while sleep 1; do tput sc; tput cup 0 $(($(tput cols)-29)); date; tput rc; done &
CLOCK_PID=$!
tail -f mylog.log
kill -9 $CLOCK_PID
```

I searched how to trap `CTRL+C` in bash, but I'm not sure it's the right way...

Comment: Doesn't `kill -TERM` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CLOCK_PID=$!
trap 'kill -9 $CLOCK_PID' EXIT
tail -f mylog.log
```

Comment: It works! Basically you have trapped the `EXIT` signal instead of the `CTRL-C` one? I think another error I did is that I put the `trap` *after* tail...

Comment: @lorenzo-s There is no `EXIT` signal. That's a special term. `man bash`: "If  a sigspec is EXIT (0) the command arg is executed on exit from the shell."

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `watch` will suit your needs.  It prints the current time by default.  Something like:

`$ watch tail -n 30 /var/log/syslog`